# Не могу вызвать метод из контроллера

Tags: java, javafx

Пишу приложение используя JavaFX, работаю с таблицами, хочу вызвать метод в контроллере, который написан в Main, но почему-то не вижу его. Для большего понятия, что происходит указал подробнее коментарии в коде.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private Stage menu;
    private BorderPane mainWindow;

    //коллекция, которую я хочу в итоге передать в контроллер
    private ObservableList<TableIncome> incomeData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public Main(){
        // В качестве образца добавляю некоторые данные
        //TableIncome - это класс типа Model
        incomeData.add(new TableIncome("Доход1"));
        incomeData.add(new TableIncome("Доход2"));
        incomeData.add(new TableIncome("Доход3"));
    }

    //этот метод хочу вызвать в контроллере
    public ObservableList<TableIncome> getIncomeData() {
        return incomeData;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        this.menu = primaryStage;
        this.menu.setTitle("Домашняя Бухгалтерия");

        initMenuBar();
        initMainWindow();
    }

    /**
     * Инициализирую menuBar.
     */
    public void initMenuBar() {
        try {
            //идет вызов FXML файла
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Загружает в корневой макет mainWindow.
     */
    public void initMainWindow() {
        try {
            //идет вызов FXML файла

            // Тут я даю контроллеру доступ к главному приложению.
            MainWindowController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMain(this); // компилятор ругается на this, пишет, 
                                      //что setMain (com.sun.tools.javac.Main)
                                      //in MainWindowController cannot be applied, не понимаю почему
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Далее класс контроллер, где пытаюсь вызвать ранее указанный метод `getIncomeData`

```
public class MainWindowController {
@FXML
private TableView<TableIncome> tableIncomeTableView;
@FXML
private TableColumn<TableIncome, String> type;
// Ссылка на главное приложение.
    private Main main;

    public MainWindowController() {
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        // Инициализация таблицы
        type.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().typeProperty());
    }

    /**
     * Вызывается главным приложением, которое даёт на себя ссылку.
     *
     * @param main
     */
    public void setMain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;

        // Добавление в таблицу данных из наблюдаемого списка
        tableIncomeTableView.setItems(main.getIncomeData);
    }
}
```

Попытался указать все максимально подробно и не слишком длинно. Сам вопрос еще раз в том, почему я не вижу метод `getIncomeData` в классе контроллера? Что я не понимаю, что нужно еще раз почитать для большего понимания, и как исправить мне это? Большое спасибо за любые одекватные ответы/комментарии

Comment: импорты проверьте, скорее всего у вас в начале `MainWindowController.java` стоит `import com.sun.tools.javac.Main;`

Comment: @zRrr , да, это и является причиной, правда появились новые вопросы, но это уже другая тема, спасибо